# postfix + opendkim not signing correctly. how to debug this?

Tags: postfix, dkim

EDIT: I did get a little further but all posts on my search say permissions are wrong or regenerate key but I fixed that to be 644 as well as owned by DKIM AND I keep regenerating the key but it is not helping.  My latest error now is this

```
Apr 21 21:19:12 Sniffy opendkim[8729]: BB5BF3AA66: dkim_eom(): resource unavailable: d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed
Apr 21 21:19:12 Sniffy postfix/cleanup[8627]: BB5BF3AA66: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 4.7.0 resource unavailable; from=<dean@abcs.com> to=<dean.hiller@gmail.com> proto=SMTP helo=<abcs.com>
```

I am looking for a way to simply debug this(don't necessarily need the answer but a way to get logs from opendkim would be good).

If I stop opendkim, I see postfix log connection refused which is good.  but when I send mail with opendkim started, I see no logs whatsoever.  I even add the "LogWhy Yes" line to my opendkim.conf file as well and still see no logs there.

Since I see opendkim running under user opendkim, I changed the owner of /etc/opendkim/* and /etc/opendkim and /etc/opendkim.conf all to opendkim user.

I am running on ubuntu.  My opendkim.conf file is

```
# Log to syslog
Syslog                  yes
# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
UMask                   002

# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/mail/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
#Domain                 example.com
Domain                  sniffyapp.com
#KeyFile                /etc/mail/dkim.key
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/default.private
#Selector               2007
Selector                default

# Commonly-used options; the commented-out versions show the defaults.
#Canonicalization       simple
Mode                    sv
#SubDomains             no
#ADSPDiscard            no

Socket inet:8891:localhost
ExternalIgnoreList refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
LogWhy Yes
```

I of course have these lines added to main.cf in postfix

```
smtpd_milters         = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters     = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept
```

Comment: What is the output of running `file /etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/default.private`?

Comment: output is root@Sniffy:~# file /etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/default.private 
/etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/default.private: PEM RSA private key

Comment: What is the permissions of /etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/default.private and each file above it, via ls -l?  (ie ls -l /etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/default.private /etc/opendkim/keys/sniffyapp.com/ /etc/opendkim/keys/ /etc/opendkim/ /etc/

Comment: they were all opendkim owned.

Comment: Try to `strace` opendkim process while you are trying to send. Might give you some insight on what's going on..

Answer (score 6):

The below line for setting Canonicalization can sometimes help. At least it worked for me very recently.

```
Canonicalization        relaxed/relaxed
```